# React-table breaks when changing data source

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-table

I've set up a basic table using react-table.

When I import the data via a file with an array of objects defined inside all works well, but when I instead store the data in a variable which stores an array of objects received via a fetch call, the code no longer works and instead gives this error:

```
> TypeError: data.map is not a function
```

```
-ContactsPage.js-
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

// Temporary Data
import ContactContent from '../components/contacts-list';

import {
  useTable,
} from 'react-table'

const ContactsPage = () => { 
  // ContactsPage is an anon function with code {...} no params are passed in

  const [ tableData, setTableData ] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await fetch(`/api/contact/data`);
      const body = await result.json();
      setTableData(body);
    }
    fetchData();
  },[])

  console.log(tableData);

  //Columns definition
  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'Name',
        columns: [
          {
            Header: 'First Name',
            accessor: 'firstName',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Last Name',
            accessor: 'lastName',
 ...shortened...




  function Table({ columns, data }) {
    const {
    // equivalent to : const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow, } = useTable({ columns, data, })
      getTableProps,
      getTableBodyProps,
      headerGroups,
      rows,
      prepareRow,
    } = useTable({
      columns,
      data,
      })


    return (
      <>
        <h1>Contacts</h1>
        <table {...getTableProps()}>
          <thead>
            {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
              <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                  <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </thead>
          <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
            {rows.map(
              (row, i) => {
                prepareRow(row);
                return (
                  <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                    {row.cells.map(cell => {
                      return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                    })}
                  </tr>
                )}
            )}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </>
    );
  }


  const data = React.useMemo(() => ContactContent, [])

  return (
    <Styles>
      <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
    </Styles>
  )
}

export default ContactsPage;
```

Just a bit lost on what is causing this. I did try to console.log the data back out to see if that was the issue, but I am receiving an array with 2 objects in it as I expected so the data looks good to me.

Comment: Its hard to tell from your example but your issue is probably this: with a fetch call, `tableData` is not immediately available. The table is trying to render `tableData` right away, before you actually have any data which is why you are getting that error. You need to wrap your component in something like this `{ tableData && (<Component .../>) }` so that it only tries to render once you actually have data from the fetch call and not before

Comment: I think you are right. The table was breaking because it was trying to render the data before it had been passed to the data variable. The fetch call is contained within useEffect which I understand will not happen until after the page is rendered further confirming that was the issue. What I did was instead pass ```const [ tableData, setTableData ] = useState({});``` an empty array rather than an empty object so that the table would have that to render before useEffect triggers. This seems to have solved the issue.